# Channel Decoding: Gaussian Channel as Time-Varying Binary Symmetric

Tags: probability, statistics, computer-science, information-theory, coding-theory

I am reading *Information Theory, Inference and Learning Algorithms* by David MacKay. It is available free of charge online: http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/itila/book.html (official site, not pirated copy).

My question is to solve *Exercise 25.1*. It is marked as one of the easier ones. I think I'm just missing some fundamental understanding.
Assistance would be enormously appreciated!

I quote the desired section, slightly paraphrased for abbreviation.
It is from Section 25.1 on Page 324 (Page 336 of my pdf).

---

A codeword $t$ is selected from a code with codewords which form a subset of $\{0,1\}^N$ and transmitted over a noisy channel and $y$ is received.
We have
$$ P(t \mid y) = P(y \mid t) P(t) / P(y) $$
by Bayes's theorem.
Assume that he channel is memoryless.
Thus
$$ P(y \mid t) = \prod_{n=1}^N P(y_n \mid t_n). $$

For example, if the channel is a Gaussian channel with transmissions $\pm x$ and additive noise of standard deviation $\sigma$, then the probability density of the received signal $y_n$ in the two cases $t_n \in \{0,1\}$ are given as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(y_n \mid t_n = 1) &= (2 \pi \sigma^2)^{-1/2} \exp\bigl( - (y_n - x)^2 / (2 \sigma^2) \bigr);
\\
P(y_n \mid t_n = 0) &= (2 \pi \sigma^2)^{-1/2} \exp\bigl( - (y_n + x)^2 / (2 \sigma^2) \bigr).
\end{aligned}
$$
[Here we are interpreting $t_n = 0$ as "send $-x$" and $t_n = 1$ as "send $+x$" (plus noise).]
From the point of view of decoding, all that matters is the *likelihood ratio*:
$$
\frac
{P(y_n \mid t_n = 1)}
{P(y_n \mid t_n = 0)}
=
\exp\biggl( \frac{2 x y_n}{\sigma^2} \biggr).
$$

*Exercise*. Show that from the point of view of decoding a Gaussian channel is equivalent to a time-varying binary symmetric channel with a known noise level $f_n$ which depends on $n$.

For further reference, Section 11.2 (Page 179 of book and 191 of my pdf) discusses inferring the input from a Gaussian channel. It's not so helpful for this, though.
I do not see what is time-varying about this.

---

PS Multiple different SE networks seemed appropriate for this: maths, cstheory, stats.
I picked this one but if a mod wants to move it, no objection from me.

Comment: You have done the work. From the decoder POV, there are only four possible cases; two of which constitute correct detection of $\pm x$, and two result in error, i.e., a binary symmetric channel. The probabilities change over $n$, so it is time variant. You already have the results. :)

Comment: Thanks, @Arash, for your response. I am happy with the binary symmetric part. The bit that I don't see is why it's _time-varying_ It seems to me that one always uses the same Normal distribution and thus always has the same likelihood ratio... there is no real $n$-dependence in the final formula: just replace $y_n$ with some other generic letter. Oh, is here $y_n$ supposed to be some given data, not a function? The book (and statisticians in general, I feel) is incredibly sloppy regarding this notation and it confuses me often!

Comment: Tell you what, I'll write my own answer to the question, then would you confirm if it's correct? `:-)`

Comment: Ok @Arash, I have written an answer. Perhaps you would be willing to check it for me? I'm not really sure how to convert the likelihood ratio to the noise...

Comment: The optimum decision making is based on MAP (maximum *a posteriori* probability) which requires the *a priori* knowledge. In order to fully characterize the equivalent binary symmetric channel, that prior knowledge ($P(y|t)$) should be taken into account, which improves over $n$, i.e., the more you have samples, the more precisely you can evaluate the prior. In that sense, receiver's understanding of the binary channel (not the Gaussian channel) is time-variant. Right now, you are using a Maximum Likelihood, which is a technique inherently ignorant of the prior probability. That's how I c it:)

Comment: And sorry for the delay. I just saw your comments. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, @Arash, for your reply I appreciate it `:)` You say "Ignorant of the prior", but I wrote "the flip probability depends on the prior". If you're able to explain a little more---feel free to edit my answer if it's easier to explain that way---I'd be very grateful. Perhaps reply in a comment on the answer, rather than here, though?

Comment: I just rewrote what you have already accomplished in a telecom. eng. language! And honestly, I would throw away MacKay's book. It is quite an unpopular opinion, but I am afraid it is a bad textbook to learn information theory or statistical inference/learning from.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. It is not time-variant. I just checked MacKay's Example 25.1 and in that configuration, such an assertion is wrong. I just paraphrase what you have already established:

Assume that at instance $n$, the transmitter sends $s_n=+x$ for $t_n=1$, and $s_n=-x$ for $t_n=0$. The receiver gets $y_n=s_n+\nu$, where $\nu \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, so, $y_n \sim \mathcal{N}(s_n, \sigma^2)$. The ML decoder is simply:
$$ \exp\left(\frac{2xy_n}{\sigma^2}\right) \overset{+x}{\underset{-x}{\gtrless}} 1 \Longrightarrow y_n \overset{t_n=1}{\underset{t_n=0}{\gtrless}} 0 $$

that is, it decides based on the sign of $y_n$.
Now,
$$\begin{align*}
\Pr\{\text{Error}|t_n=1\} & = \Pr\{y_n<0|t_n=1\}=\Pr\{y_n<0|s_n=+x\} = Q\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right) \\
\Pr\{\text{Correct}|t_n=1\} & = \Pr\{y_n>0|t_n=1\}=\Pr\{y_n>0|s_n=+x\} = 1-Q\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right) \\
\Pr\{\text{Error}|t_n=0\} & = \Pr\{y_n>0|t_n=0\}=\Pr\{y_n>0|s_n=-x\} = Q\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right) \\
\Pr\{\text{Correct}|t_n=0\} & = \Pr\{y_n<0|t_n=0\}=\Pr\{y_n<0|s_n=-x\} = 1-Q\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right) \\
\end{align*}$$

which describes a *time-invariant* binary symmetric channel.

Comment: Set $x := 1 =: \sigma^2$. Assume a uniform prior on $t$. Suppose I see $y_1 = 1/1000$. I decode it to $s_1 = +x$, ie $t_1 = 1$ but know that it's basically 50:50 whether this is correct or not. Suppose I see $y_2 = 10000000$. I again decode this to $s_2 = +x$, ie $t_2 = 1$. I now know that the odds that I'm right is roughly $e^{20000000} : 1$---ie almost certain. I think MacKay is saying, "look at your full sequence $y = (y_1, ..., y_N)$; now what is the error probability?" This is calculating $\Pr(\text{error} \mid y_n)$, rather than $\Pr(\text{error} \mid t_n)$. This way it is time varying

Comment: I thought that too. Then again I read the MacKay's text, and I'm afraid it was just plain wrong. I don't know much, but that's what I thought.

Comment: Hmm :/ -- my _impression_ from his book in general suggests that he did mean that the sequence $y$ is observed, giving rise to the time-inhomogeneity that I suggest. But it certainly is far from clear. Perhaps this is another section to go in your "evidence for why the book is bad" collection!

Comment: Perhaps! But seriously, I prefer Thomas Cover's *Elements of Information Theory*, except for the 2nd chapter, which I prefer Robert Ash's. Also Mehryar Mohri's *Foundations of Machine Learning*, specially chapters 2, 3, 12, 13, and Appendix E, which gives a boost to information theory in ML literature.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I was mostly reading for the introduction to Neural Networks. I'm more than 300 pages in, just about to get to the NN part! I always saw CT as more of a _reference_. A bit long to read Cover to Cover (pun intended!). I'll certainly check out the other book you reference, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Arash presents one possibility. Here is another. It gives a *completely different* conclusion. MacKay's text appears ambiguous to which is intended.

---

Although it looks like a variable, here $y = (y_n)_{n \in [N]}$ is a single given realisation---the expression
$$
\frac
{P(y_n \mid t_n = 1)}
{P(y_n \mid t_n = 0)}
=
\exp\biggl( \frac{2 x y_n}{\sigma^2} \biggr)
$$
is not to be thought of as expressing a function of $y_n$.
Rather, let $q_n(b) := P(y_n \mid t_n = b)$---this is a function of the bit $b \in \{0,1\}$.
The likelihood ratio is saying that
$$
\frac{q_n(1)}{q_n(0)} = \exp( 2 x y_n / \sigma^2 ).
$$
Thus it is a binary symmetric channel with time-varying flip-probability.
Converting this into the flip parameter $f_n$ requires knowledge of the prior.
For example, if the prior is uniform, then *I think*
$$
\frac{1 - f_n}{f_n} = \frac{q_n(1)}{q_n(0)},
\quad\text{ie}\quad
f_n = \frac1{1 + q_n(1)/q_n(0)}.
$$
*I could be mistaken with this final claim, however.*